# How to use Eloquent model property in subquery?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables (`users`, `posts`) and I'm trying to order `users` according to recent post's date.

But unfortunately I couldn't find a way to use User model's `firebase_id` to use in subquery. I don't want to use raw query or DB directly if it's possible to use Eloquent for such query.

How can I use User model's `firebase_id` as subquery parameter?

Here is my non-working code to give an idea about what I try to do:

```php
    User::select('users.*', DB::raw("SELECT MAX(id) FROM posts WHERE posts.firebase_id = users.firebase_id as recent_post_date"))
         ->whereHas('posts', function ($q) {
                $q->withCount('comments');
         })
         ->with(['posts' => function ($q) {
                $q->withCount('comments')
                   ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC');
         }])
         ->orderBy('recent_post_date', 'DESC')
         ->get();
```

Comment: you are trying to do more: you need to get those posts with comments.

Comment: The problem is about sorting Users in fact.. If I can run the subquery and sort by "recent_post_date", it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `selectSub` to add a subquery.

Try the following

```
$recentPostQuery = Post::select('created_at')
    ->whereColumn('firebase_id', 'users.firebase_id')
    ->latest()
    ->limit(1)
    ->getQuery();

User::select('users.*')
    ->selectSub($recentPostQuery, 'recent_post_date')
    ->whereHas('posts', function ($q) {
            $q->withCount('comments');
    })
    ->with(['posts' => function ($q) {
            $q->withCount('comments')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC');
    }])
    ->orderBy('recent_post_date', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you @chanafdo, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with QueryBuilder and a join:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->join('posts.firebase_id ', '=', 'users.firebase_id ')
    ->orderBy('posts.recent_post_date', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

**UPDATE**
You asked for Eloquent. You can do it with `whereHas`.

```
$users = User::whereHas('posts', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->orderBy('posts.recent_post_date', 'DESC');
})->get();
```

Comment: Thank you @Giacomo M, that's also a good approach but I want to use subquery on another purpose too.